# ftp client -- random characters are inserted after get

Tags: c++, ftp

I'm creating an FTP client in C++.

After downloading a larger file using my ftp client. I see random characters that get added to the file here and there.

[image]

In the picture, `protocol` became `pr¿_ÿotocol`, they are also inserted in many other spots in the same file.

I noticed:

- These characters vary when i changed the buffer size, sometimes `\377`, or a backslash followed by 3 digits
- They become more frequent when buffer size is reduced

I made sure to use Image Mode. What could be causing this?

My reading code in `TCPSocket`:

```
stringstream TCPSocket::long_read()
{
    pollfd ufds;
    ufds.fd = sd;
    ufds.events = POLLIN;
    ufds.revents = 0;
    ssize_t bytesRead = 0;
    stringstream result;
    char buf[BUFF_SIZE];
    do {
        bzero(buf, BUFF_SIZE);

        bytesRead = ::read(sd, buf, BUFF_SIZE);
        if (bytesRead == 0) {
            break;
        }
        if (bytesRead > 0) {
            result << buf;
        }
    } while (poll(&ufds, 1, 1000) > 0);
    return result;
}
```

My Get code in Main.cpp

```
 else if (command == command::GET) {
        string filename;
        cin >> filename;
        string dataHost;
        int dataPort;
        if (enterPasiveMode(dataHost, dataPort)) {
            dataSocket = new TCPSocket(dataHost.c_str(), dataPort);
            if (fork() == 0) {
                stringstream result = dataSocket->long_read();

                ofstream ofs;

                ofs.open(filename);
                if (ofs.is_open()) {
                    copy(istreambuf_iterator<char>(result), istreambuf_iterator<char>(), ostreambuf_iterator<char>(ofs));

                    ofs.close();
                }
                else {
                    cout << "open failed";
                }
                break;
            }
            else {
                writeAndImmediateRead(rfc959::TYPE_I);
                controlSocket->write(rfc959::RETRIVE(filename));
                string result = controlSocket->read();
                cout << result;
                int reply = Parser::firstDigit(result);

                // I'll remove incomplete local file if request fails
                if (reply != rfc959::POSITIVE_PRELIMINARY_REPLY) {
                    remove(filename.c_str());
                    continue;
                }

                wait(NULL);
                cout << controlSocket->long_read().str();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your `long_read´ function:

```
char buf[BUFF_SIZE];
...
    bytesRead = ::read(sd, buf, BUFF_SIZE);
    ...
        result << buf;
```

buf is a `char[]` which means that when used as a string the data are expected to end with `\0`. Which in itself means that the `<<` will not necessary add `bytesRead` to `result` but anything up to the first `\0`. Depending on the data this can be before `bytesRead` or even after, in which case you get data from the unitialized `buf` until it finds some `\0`. This `\0` could even be outside `buf`.

Or in short: don't mix string semantics (`char[]`,`<<`,...) and octet semantics (`::read(...)`).

Comment: What should be used to store and concatenate `bytesRead` instead?

Comment: @tomtom: you could for example convert char[] to string by giving the size instead of letting it compute the size from the final \0, i.e. use `string(const char *s, size_t n)` constructor. See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/string/.

Comment: now I'm having a problem where the `CR/LF` [characters are removed](http://imgur.com/MjzbVPF). How could this be? I have made sure to use Image mode. Here's my [code](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/b2207ca760f751c136c7),  I'm on a mac and server is ubuntu.

Comment: @tomtom: this is strange, especially because you are not reading or writing line-wise. Thus I suspect you get the data the wrong way already which means that either your `TYPE I` command is wrong (do you check for successful reply?) or it is ignored by the server or the data are bad on the server already.

Comment: for whoever found this question through a search engine--  I think this fixed my problem